# Htaccess RewriteRule not passing parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I had a Plesk Onyx server, running on Centos 7.2, Apache 2.4 Nginx is OFF, I had the following htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.js|\.css|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.ttf|\.woff|\.woff2|\.otf|\.eot|\.ico|\.svg|\.txt|\.xml|\.json)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/([0-9]+)/(.*)[/]$ /folder1/folder2/index.php?get_var=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

The rwwite works OK but its not passing the get_var
in index.php I had a var_dump ($_GET) and it is empty if I visit
https://sample_domain.com/folder1/folder2/123/

I want to get the 123 value into the get_var
tried disabling -MultiViews and no luck

Comment: Change your `Options` line to `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That rule can't be working at all for the URL you presented. It would only work for something like:

```
https://sample_domain.com/folder1/folder2/123//
```

Or:

```
https://sample_domain.com/folder1/folder2/123/example/
```

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/folder1/folder2/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/([0-9]+)/$ /folder1/folder2/index.php?get_var=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

I removed unnecessary tests since it could only be a directory. And I guess you don't even need that test? Do you have existing directories in `/folder1/folder2/` named only with numbers? If not remove that test to improve performance.

**Update**

To operate this out of a `.htaccess` file in `/folder1/folder2/`, change it to be as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?get_var=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: i still dont get the $_GET['get_var'] inside index.php

Comment: Then you must have some other rule interfering with this.

Comment: thats all what i had for rewrite rules

Comment: Well it works perfectly for me with this rule, $_GET['get_var'] gives me '123'. Is your .htaccess in the root of the site?

Comment: no, its in a subfolder, this applies to only that folder

Comment: Well the above is written to be in the root `.htaccess` file. If you want to put it in a folder then let me know which one and I can update my answer.

Comment: So which folder?

Comment: /folder1/folder2/ the 123 its a variable param

Comment: how can i make it work if the url doesnt had the last / https://sample_domain.com/folder1/folder2/123